# jQuery AJAX request on local development environment fail

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to test a jQuery/Javascript script on my local development environment. For some reason the script calls the error delegate. I've attempted to make sure I'm not performing a cross-domain request.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    return marker;
}
```

I'm running a WAMP stack. Here is my output:

```
error
undefined
XMLHttpRequest { mozResponseArrayBuffer=ArrayBuffer, status=0, more...}
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the absolute url:

```
url: 'http://localhost'
```

with a relative one:

```
url: '/'
```

If this doesn't solve your problem [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and/or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will give you more hints about what is going on and why the AJAX request fails.